# siunitx display uncertainty of zero

Tags: siunitx

I would like to have uncertainties of zero (variance estimates) displayed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\num[separate-uncertainty=true]{1 +- 0.0}
\end{document}
```

Actual rendering:

```
 1±
```

Hoping for:

```
 1±0.0
```

Comment: I don't exactly remember the rules, but the number of decimal places should be the same: `{1.0+-0.0}` instead of `{1+-0.0}`.

Comment: I do not know if what you are doing is wrong, but I found this in the manual: `\num[separate-uncertainty = true]{1.234(5)}`

Comment: @campa I see, \num[separate-uncertainty=true]{1.0 +- 0.0} works, but \num[separate-uncertainty=true]{1 +- 0} does not (no display at all?)

Comment: @hpekristiansen I am aware of that notational alternatives. Interestingly \num[separate-uncertainty=true]{1(0)} is ok, while `{1 +- 0}` is not? \num[separate-uncertainty=true]{1.0(0)} works also; \num[separate-uncertainty=true]{1.0(0.0)} does not, \num[separate-uncertainty=true]{1(0.0)} also renders void.

Answer (score 9):

A correct syntax consists in writing the uncertainty as an integer between parentheses. This is interpreted as a number with a decimal part having as many digits as the ‘main’ number.

Demo:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\sisetup{separate-uncertainty=true}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  \num{1.00 (10)} & \num{1.00 (2)} \\[2ex]
  \num{1.0 (10)} & \num{1.0 (2)} \\[2ex]
  \num{1 (10)} & \num{1 (2)}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 You should show this working with a zero uncertainty.

Comment: @Andrew Swann: Well, what happens, except an absurd uncertainty of $\pm0$?

Comment: Indeed it is absurd, but it was the OP is asking for.

Comment: This reminds me of a dialog in an old French one-woman show: ‘It's so cold, darling! The temperature is minus zero…’. I wonder what would be –0°K?

Comment: I agree with the absurdity of zero uncertainty, but the OP's code `\num[separate-uncertainty=true]{1 +- 0.0}` works for any uncertainty other than 0, e.g. `\num[separate-uncertainty=true]{1 +- 0.1}` so with the syntax the OP is using things go wrong specifically when the uncertainty is specified as `0` using a different number of decimal points (`\num[separate-uncertainty=true]{1.0 +- 0.0}` also works fine for example)

Comment: a) as @DaiBowen points out, this is about inconsistent behavior and b) whether a zero uncertainty is absurd or not is to be judged in the context of reporting.